# How to select a column next to a named range?

Tags: vba

[image]

The red range is called theRange. How do I select the yellow range using VBA code?

Comment: `Range("theRange").Offset(,1).Select` should do the trick

Comment: @JNevill That worked. Thank you! Wasn't aware of such a magical function.

Comment: The `Offset()` and `Resize()` methods of the `Range` object are truly like magic. You can get to anywhere from anywhere with those. I've added as an answer since it did the trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.Offset(<rows>, <columns>)` method of the `Range` object to do this:

```
Range("theRange").Offset(,1).Select
```

Comment: Upvoted. Just a note to mention that OP *likely* doesn't *need* to `.Select` anything (hard to tell just from the question though).